# OpenGL program to draw a triangle gives a yellow screen

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glfw

I am trying to draw a triangle with OpenGL.

My code compiles fine, and does not produce any errors but it still does not do what its supposed to.

I have a vertex shader and a fragment shader and both of them are in the same program.

My code is below:

```
#include "../../include/sb7.h"

GLuint compile_shaders(void)
{
    GLuint vertex_shader;
    GLuint fragment_shader;
    GLuint program;

    // Source code for Vertex Shader
    static const GLchar * vertex_shader_source[] =
    {
        "#version 450 core                                                  \n"
        "                                                                   \n"
        "void main(void)                                                    \n"
        "{                                                                  \n"
        "   //Decalre a hardcoded array of positions                        \n"
        "   const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](vec4(0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),   \n"
        "                                    vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),  \n"
        "                                    vec4(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0));   \n"
        "   //Index into our array using gl_VertexID                        \n"
        "   gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];                            \n"
        "}                                                                  \n"
    };

    // Source code for Fragment Shader
    static const GLchar * fragment_shader_source[] =
    {
        "#version 450 core                                  \n"
        "                                                   \n"
        "out vec4 color;                                    \n"
        "                                                   \n"
        "void main(void)                                    \n"
        "{                                                  \n"
        "   color = vec4(0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0);               \n"
        "}                                                  \n"
    };

    // Create and compiler Vertex Shader
    vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, vertex_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

    // Create and compiler Fragment Shader
    fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, fragment_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);

    // Create program, attach shaders to it, and link it
    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    // Delete shaders as program has them now
    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);

    return program;
};

class my_application : public sb7::application
{
public:

    void startup()
    {
        rendering_program = compile_shaders();
        glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
        glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);
    }

    void shutdown()
    {
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
        glDeleteProgram(rendering_program);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
    }

    // Our rendering function
    void render(double currentTime)
    {
        // Sets Colour
        static const GLfloat color[] = { 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);

        // Use program object we created for rendering
        glUseProgram(rendering_program);

        // Draw one triangle
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }

private:

    GLuint rendering_program;
    GLuint vertex_array_object;
};
```

I am following the OpenGL Superbible, 7th edition.

The same program (with small changes) was also not drawing a point even when I changed the point size and the output was the same screen (full yellow) that I am getting for this.

I have seen similar problems that arise during drawing of triangles but they are all different from what I'm doing.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't see where you override `init()` which calls the required `sb7::application::init()`

Comment: The book did not say anything about overriding `sb7::application's init().`
It only said to override `render(), startup(), and shutdown()`

Comment: I was looking at `SB7dir\scr\singletri`, which seems your base. It overrides `init()` so as to be able to set some details. See `SB7dir\include\sb7.h` In your case, this function is setting a 4.3 context, while you ask for 4.5 in your shaders.

Comment: what did the GLSL compilation and link logs say? (look here [how glsl_log is obtained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)) my bet is that your shaders source code text is not encoded as ASCII as should ... try to use files if it make a difference. If yes than you need to add some kind of `_TEXT("bla bla bla")` macro to compensate.

Comment: I changed mine to a 4.3 context too now, but it is just displaying a yellow screen

Comment: @Ripi2 After changing it I even double checked the header files and its all the same context now. And, I've been using varying codes to do the same thing (Draw a triangle), but it still just shows a yellow screen

Comment: @Varun.R **check the GLSL logs** then (as I suggested before) my bet is that one or more of your shaders did not compile or link. The logs will hold the answer in such case (what is wrong and exactly where).

Comment: Old question, but your triangle is probably too big, and is occupying the entire screen. The fact that another user got it to run fine suggests an implementation-specific bug, like defaulting an unknown value to 0 as opposed to INF. Shrug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workin' fine here:

[image: screenshot of blue triangle on dark green background]

All together:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* shader, ... )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        va_list args;
        va_start( args, shader );
        while( shader )
        {
            const GLenum type = va_arg( args, GLenum );
            AttachShader( prog, type, shader );
            shader = va_arg( args, const char* );
        }
        va_end( args );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE;
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        GLchar log[ 1 << 15 ] = { 0 };
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        std::cerr << log << std::endl;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

const char* vert = R"GLSL(
#version 450 core                                                
void main(void)                                                  
{                                                                
    //Decalre a hardcoded array of positions                      
    const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3]
        (
        vec4(0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0), 
        vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),
        vec4(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0)
        );
    //Index into our array using gl_VertexID                      
    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];                          
}                                                                
)GLSL";

const char* frag = R"GLSL(
#version 450 core                           
out vec4 color;                             
void main(void)                             
{                                           
    color = vec4(0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0);        
}                                           
)GLSL";

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 5 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE );
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( 640, 480, "51307782", NULL, NULL );
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );
    glewInit();
    glfwSwapInterval( 1 );

    GLuint rendering_program = Program::Load
        (
        vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
        frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
        NULL
        );

    GLuint vertex_array_object = 0;
    glCreateVertexArrays( 1, &vertex_array_object );
    glBindVertexArray( vertex_array_object );

    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        static const GLfloat color[] = { 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        glClearBufferfv( GL_COLOR, 0, color );
        glUseProgram( rendering_program );
        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );

        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &vertex_array_object );
    glDeleteProgram( rendering_program );

    glfwDestroyWindow( window );
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Comment: I see your shaders are the same as mine which means if it works for you, then it should work for me too except, it isn't working for me. Was there anything you changed/added to my code?

Comment: As you did I used `const char*` instead of `static const GLchar *` for the vertex and fragment shaders. And then I passed a reference `&vert, &frag` as the third argument for the `glShaderSource` functions. But, that did not change anything and the output is still a yellow screen